# Using local memcache instance with django-heroku-memcacheify

Tags: python, django, heroku, memcached

As per the docs [here](https://github.com/rdegges/django-heroku-memcacheify) I have set-up things to use the Memcachier plug-in in production and use the local memcache instance in development. However when I do check which cache I'm using locally, I see that django is using the `LocMemCache` and not the configured memcache.

In my `settings.py`

```
from memcacheify import memcacheify

CACHES = memcacheify()
```

In the django python shell

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache
<django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache at 0x9afd7ac>
```

Environment settings

```
MEMCACHE_BACKEND=django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache
MEMCACHEIFY_USE_LOCAL=True
MEMCACHIER_SERVERS=127.0.0.1:11211
MEMCACHIER_USERNAME=
MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you double-check that your not getting a key error for:

```
import os; os.environ['MEMCACHEIFY_USE_LOCAL']
```

You'll need to ensure [this condition](https://github.com/rdegges/django-heroku-memcacheify/blob/1ba73004b3f5823588bb67986c16e95bfb62db6c/memcacheify.py#L59) is passing. If your using Foreman to configure the environment, make sure your using the proper tooling to run the Django shell.